# Laravel: How to specify returned data with a Broadcast?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.6, laravel-echo

I'm working with a Presence Channel and according to the [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/broadcasting#presence-channels), you can return a specific array of data of what you need. e.g. in this case, it's the `id` and `name` from the variable `$user`.

```
Broadcast::channel('chat', function ($user) {
    return ['id' => $user->id, 'name' => $user->name];
});
```

In my JS file I have

```
Echo.join(`chat`)
.here((users) => {
  console.log('users here: ',users);
})
```

The `console.log()` returns an array of **all** user data (like email addresses) instead of just the `id` and `name` that I specified in the `Broadcast`.

How can I only make it contain the `id` and `name` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I restarted the browser and it just started working as normal... odd. There seems to be some type of caching thing going on that is not *within* the browser but perhaps on the Pusher side of things.. I'm not sure.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, `Broadcast::channel` takes an `authentication callback` to authenticate whether the user is allowed to listen to this channel. This is **not** the data payload, this array is for authentication!

To specify the data payload use `broadcastWith` as specified in the [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/broadcasting#broadcast-data)

Comment: For whatever reason, it's now just started working like magic as I originally intended it to. What you're talking about is broadcasting events. I'm not using **events** but merely subscribing to a channel. I believe you are incorrect in your answer.

Comment: Oops missed that you're working with presence channels. My bad